# How to live editing map on seatchart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use [seatchart.js](https://seatchart.js.org/) to design a venue layout, is there any chance that I can do live editing on the seatchart options?

Let say I want to change the row and column number by edit the textfield, but I didn't see any hook or function that I can use to re-render the map layout.

This is my default options and I'm trying to change the rows and columns number.

```
 const options = {
    map: {
      rows: 3,
      columns: 3,
      seatTypes: {
        default: {
          label: "Bronze",
          cssClass: "bronze",
          price: 80
        },
      },
      reserved: [],
      rowSpacers: [],
      columnSpacers: [],
      disabledSeats: [],
      reservedSeats: [],
    },
    cart: {
      visible: false
    },
  }
```

I create this form in react

[Layout Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgOSQ.png)

I expect the map will updated after I change the row/column number.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my library to [react-seat-picker](https://github.com/roggervalf/react-seat-picker) and I just need to add key in the SeatPicker tag like this

```
<SeatPicker
    key={randomKey}
...
```

And make sure to always generate some random key when the value updated.